# changing app-ID

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, app-id

I have an iPhone app (Show of Hands) that has been a freebie for nearly two years, with about 100,000 downloads. Now I want to enable in-app purchases to let users turn off iAds, but I cannot do so because I originally used a wildcard App-ID. Wildcard IDs can't support in-app-purchases...

Is it possible to change my existing App-ID without creating a new app, and not break the upgrade path etc. for all of my existing users?

Thanks!

Comment: And you probably should accept some answer of your previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the App-ID of your provisioning profile doesn't change anything about your app. Just use the new App-ID without changing your bundle ID and you're good to go.